# Whats the best way to populate two tables with records that need to reference each other?

Tags: php, mysql, reference, referential-integrity

What is the best way to populate records in two tables that each need a reference to the primary key of the other?

My thoughts are either having a "link" table between them which is populated once both have been written to the db or by the following complex series  of commands

```
Insert1
get identity1
Insert2 
get identity2
update 1
```

How would you do this in PHP whilst connected to a mySQL Database and maintain integrity?

Would you need to use transactions, if so how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Can I ask why the tables need to reference each other. If it is a straight 1:1 then I would suggest just putting the foreign key in one of the tables. the lookup is just as easy. And your foreign key can be properly enforced. otherwise you run into a chicken/egg scenario where the tables both need to reference each other. but one needs to be created first. This means at a certain point your database will be in a non consistent state.

Comment: To be honest I'm asking SO because I colleague asked me and I thought it would be quicker to probe the collective hivemind. So I don't know what the context is.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must do it , then definitely use transactions - to avoid orphan records

```
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
if(!mysql_query($query1))
{   $errmsg=mysql_error();
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
}
else
{  $id1=mysql_insert_id();
   $query2="insert into.....$id1...");
   if(!mysql_query($query2))
   {   $errmsg=mysql_error();
       mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
   }
   $id2=mysql_insert_id();
   if(!mysql_query("update tabel1 set my_key=$id2 where key=$id1"))
   {   $errmsg=mysql_error();
       mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
   }

}
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use transactions. MySql supports this in newer versions, if you use the InnoDb storage engine (But not for MyIsam).